# Arango spring-data documentation no longer current. Not clear what you should do for new coding model

Tags: spring-data, arangodb, java-11

I am struggling with changes in the most current arangodb-spring-data project code that doesn't align with the older documentation.

Here is my refreshed gradle build dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    id 'groovy'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
...

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    //implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy'
    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.0-rc-1'

//    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.3-groovy-2.5'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'com.arangodb:arangodb-spring-data:3.2.3'
    implementation  'com.arangodb:arangodb-java-driver:6.4.1'
}
```

I have a arangoConfiguration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableArangoRepositories(basePackages = [ "com.softwood.arango" ])
class ArangoConfiguration extends AbstractArangoConfiguration {  //changed since 3.2.0
//class ArangoConfiguration  {


    @Override
    public Builder arango() {
        return new ArangoDB.Builder().host("localhost", 8529).user("root").password(null)
    }

    @Override
    public String database() {
        return "testDB"
    }
}
```

However in the IDE it now shows that `extends AbstractArangoConfiguration` is deprecated.  There is now an interface instead called ArangoConfiguration in my ArangoConfiguration class.

I tried changing the code to implements this interface and it doesn't work, as I get a bean dependency failure with ArangoOperations not being defined - which if you extend the deprecated abstract class doesn't happen.  Spring fails on injecting the operations autowired bean - if you try and implement from the `ArangoConfiguration` interface in the copy of the demo code is here in github [sample code](https://github.com/woodmawa/arango).

My CrudRunner looks like this

```
@ComponentScan("com.softwood.arango")
public class CrudRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ArangoOperations operations
    @Autowired
    private OrganisationRepository orgRepo

    @Autowired
    private SiteRepository siteRepo

    @Autowired
    private OperatesFromManyRepository ownsRepo  //edge relationship
    ....
```

The code works if I revert to the deprecated model approach - however I still get separate unrelated warning with a reflection problem using Java 11.0.5.  This doesn't stop it working but the code base is doing something that Java 11 doesn't like.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/C:/Users/will/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.RELEASE/e0e1b3c304f70ed19d7905975f6f990916ada219/spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

There is nothing updated on the arangodb-spring-data usage documentation to reflect the go forward way  with the new interface.

What should the latest version V.3.0+ versions look like?

The Java 11 warning is a problem - but the code still seems to run but will need a fix; it doesn't happen on Java 8.

If any one knows the new approach can they share that, else I'll have to post across on the Git project pages.

Comment: partial - went back and tried again with this `class ArangoConfiguration implements com.arangodb.springframework.config.ArangoConfiguration {
` and this time didn't get the dependency failure - just the the Java 11 warning.  Will try and press on tomorrow

Comment: If you are ok using spring boot 2.1.x (and spring data 2.1) then you can use https://github.com/arangodb/spring-boot-starter which takes care of spring AutoConfigurations (https://github.com/arangodb/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/src/main/java/com/arangodb/springframework/boot/autoconfigure).
Spring Boot 2.2 (and Spring Data 2.2) are officially not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has been updated: https://github.com/arangodb/docs/pull/541

Furthermore `ArangoConfiguration` does not add anything to `AbstractArangoConfiguration`, as you can see here: https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/4ae3130af345a0314a215605aa38fb7c88d41d5b/src/main/java/com/arangodb/springframework/config/AbstractArangoConfiguration.java, and it should work exactly in the same way (except for the deprecation warning). So maybe your injection problems are due to some other reason.

Also: illegal reflective access warnings when using Java 11 are not due to Spring Data Arango, but from the Spring Framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22674